Disable Gallery and Google Photos on a Xiaomi phone
I want my pictures in the Gallery to be backed up to Google Photos but when I delete a picture in the Gallery, the picture is not deleted on Google Photos. How to disable Gallery and Google Photos sync on a Xiaomi phone?
